# Force on matter in inhomogeneous magnetic field (diamagnetism and paramagnetism)

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, matter

I found on [this site](http://wwwex.physik.uni-ulm.de/lehre/gk3b-2002-2003/node33.html) a formula (4.101). It describes wich force acts on matter in an inhomogeneous magnetic field. $ F_z = m_z * \frac{\partial B_z (z0)}{\partial z}$ 
What does the fraction consist of? What does the $z$ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call "the fraction" is the derivative of the magnetic induction in respect position along the z axis. This is the factor that measures the inhomogeneity of the magnetic field. It is actually the component of the gradient of the magnetic field along the z axis.
z is an index for one of the direction or axes in a Cartesian coordinate system. The other two directions are usually labeled x and y.
So the formula shows how the component of the magnetic force along the z axis is related to the magnetic moment along the same axis and the gradient of the magnetic field (again, along same axis).

Comment: so does the $z0$ in $\partial B_z(z0)$ mean that we just look at the change of the magnetic field in the z direction?

Comment: No, the zo indicates that you calculate the partial derivative at z=zo.